# Write a book, plant a tree, have a son?

Tags: sources-mekorot, books-generally, trees

A few non-Torah websites (not worth linking) suggest there is a Jewish source for the quote: "Plant a tree, write a book, and have a son." Is this idea found anywhere in the Torah sources?

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Kedoshim.8.1?lang=he

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.11.6.1?lang=bi&with=all